# How to import java package

Tags: java, class, import, javac

I have two folders `a` and `b`:

- in `a` I have a `ClassA.java`,
- in `b` I have a `ClassB.java`.

I want to `ClassB.java` import `ClassA.java`. How could I do that?

If I just write `import a.ClassA`, I cannot compile it.

Comment: It's a good idea put all the class in a single folder, so you can call it easily

Comment: It would be nice if you provide the code which is not compiling. otherwise we can only guess what you did wrong. ;)

Comment: Did you describe in `ClassA` that it belongs to package `a` (in other words does it starts with `package a;`)?

Comment: How are you trying to compile your class?

Comment: What does _I cannot compile it_ mean?

Comment: @Pshemo javac ClassB.java

Comment: And from which localization you are using that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like you added package declarations in your classes like

```
package a;
public class ClassA{
    //...       
}
```

and based on your question you claimed that you also included `import a.ClassA` in ClassB like

```
package b;
import a.ClassA;
public class ClassB{
    //...       
}
```

So to compile your ClassB from `b` directory you need to include in your command localization of other packages you are going to use, in this case localization of directory holding directory `a`. You do it by setting `-classpath` parameter (or shorter `-cp`).

So if you are in folder `b` you can do it via

```
javac -cp .. ClassB.java
```

where `..` means parent directory (the one holding both `a` and `b`).

To run your code you also need to point location of directory holding additional packages used by your application. So you would need to use

```
java -cp .. b.ClassB
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to declare the package within the classes, without that Information Java does not know that the imported classes belong to packages.

Comment: I am not down-voter but if you want to ask OP a question do it via comment, not answer (even if you are on the right track - answers should not be guesses).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Make sure as ChrisKo says that you include at the top of each file "package a" in ClassA.java and "package b" in ClassB.java

Comment: @Rai This part of answer "*Probably you forgot to declare the package within the classes*" can't be correct, based on OP response to [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887378/how-to-import-java-package/31887621#comment51692498_31887378). There are also other possible problems like lack of, or incorrect classpath.

Comment: Fair statement. However, after running a quick test myself with the information given by the OP (location of source files, import statements specified, and error, albeit vague error,) I was able to deduce for myself that the error must be either caused by an error in syntax or one or more missing `package` declarations.

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as the accepted answer and i provided it earlier. The only difference is that Pshemo mentioned the classpath parameter. But that would not be required when using an IDE, and that information was not given in the OPs initial question to which i responded. To be fair you should consider the amount of information which was given at the time i created my answer. It was a question with very little information and according to that information my answer was correct.

Comment: "*This is exactly the same answer as the accepted answer and i provided it earlier*" your answer points to lack of package declaration which based on OP comments is not the case. "*only difference is that Pshemo mentioned the classpath paramete*" actually information about classpath is root of my answer, rest is just to show how OP codes looks like (based on his comments). "*But that would not required when using an IDE, and that information was not given in the OPs initial question..*" and that is the problem, you posted guess as answer, instead of asking OP for clarification.

Comment: That is exactly the point. You answered based on comments which were created AFTER i provided an answer. Afterwards you edited the original question and created a new answer which is basically the same as mine. That whole thing could be much clearer if the OP added source-code. Please be fair and consider the information i had at the time of writing and not the comments which were created later on. Just saying "hey i mentioned the cp-flag" should not lead to downvoting my answer. you also could have added that info to my answer as a comment.

Comment: If you have comment and you want some person to be informed about it please add `@thatPerson` in it, like `@Pshemo`. For example I wasn't aware of your response because there was no notification. Anyway lets go back to discussion. "*Please be fair and consider the information I had at the time of writing*" you need to understand that this is NOT a race. We are here to post **correct solution**, not *guesses* which later should be discussed (Stack Overflow is not discussion forum, but question-answers site). So if you need more informations ask OP about them in comment.

Comment: So argument that "*You answered based on comments which were created AFTER i provided an answer*" doesn't really makes sense. "*Afterwards you edited the original question*" if you take a look at [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31887378/revisions) you will notice that I didn't change informations in question, but simply formatted them to increase readability. "*you ... created a new answer which is basically the same as mine*" I must disagree. Your answer suggests that there is a problem with declaration of packages in source code, while mine is about lack of proper classpath.

Comment: If you don't want to ask OP for more informations be ready to write answer which will cover all (or almost all) possible problems, not just one. Such answer are very welcome on Stack Overflow and you would not need to worry about downvotes. But in current state your answer is simply incorrect (we know that from comments) so it got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your classes look like these:

```
// ClassA.java
package a;    

class ClassA { 
  ... 
}    

// ClassB.java       
package b;

import a.ClassA;    

class ClassB {
   ...    
}
```

Your folder structure must be something like this:

```
src    
-- src/a   
----- ClassA.java   
-- src/b    
---- ClassB.java
```

Then go to *src* folder and type:

```
Javac ./a/ClassA.java ./b/ClassB.java
```

Comment: You last line should read `javac ./a/ClassA.java ./b/ClassB.java` assuming a Linux filesystem like mine or `javac .\a\ClassA.java .\b\ClassB.java` for Windows or simply `javac ./**/*.java`